# Why is there a white space between these blocks in an HTML email

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email

So this issue only shows up on the client's end when they send out the email but not on my end when designing it. I am using Dreamweaver to do this section.
This is how it shows up -

[image: Visual issue of the hairline]

This is the code that I have for this section. The top part is a white block with blue on the sides and the bottom is pure blue. This issue only shows up when the client deploys the email.

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td class="hide" width="20">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td height="39" bgcolor="#3A99A8">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
              <tr>
                <td style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td class="sideline" width="198">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td height="19">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
              <tr>
                <td style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="20" bgcolor="#3A99A8">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
              <tr>
                <td style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td width="160" bgcolor="#00558A">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="top">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center" bgcolor="#00558A">
                        <a href="https://www.clubmed.us/l/revisedcancellationpolicy" target="_blank" style="font-family: 'Happiness', 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important; color: #ffffff; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; padding: 10px 20px; border: 0; border-radius: 0; display: inline-block; text-transform: uppercase; text-decoration: none;">
                                                                            Learn more&nbsp;&nbsp;&#62;</a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td class="sideline" width="198">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td height="19">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
              <tr>
                <td style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="20" bgcolor="#3A99A8">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
              <tr>
                <td style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td class="hide" width="20">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td height="39" bgcolor="#3A99A8">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
              <tr>
                <td style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is that a screenshot from Outlook desktop on Windows? That would be the dreaded 1px white line issue. There's a ton of resources online if you google that phrase- the answer could be many things

Comment: I believe they use outlook yes

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with outlook rendering couple of month's ago and was able to fix it with this bit of code:

```
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
 <style type="text/css">
   table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
    mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important; }
  </style>
 <![endif]-->
```

I found this answer here:
https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/how-to-code-emails-for-outlook-2016/

There are some other fixes in there that could help if the Outlook specific code doesn't work.